# I need to decumentation for configration Gpon

Tags: networking, network-programming, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-account

I learn configration Gpon , i need decumentation

I expected that gpon available in configration and i can learn it from youtupe and sites but it not available in google Or  I not know access to it

I neet to help me please sier

Answer (score 0):

Documentation of Gpon configurations is available at the [link](https://support.huawei.com/enterprise/en/doc/EDOC1000174070/ef1ad957/configuring-attributes-of-a-gpon-interface).